# Show that a neccessary and sufficient condition for $X_p$ to be tangent to $S^n$ at $p$ is $\sum_{i} a^i p^i = 0$.

Tags: differential-geometry

> The unit sphere $S^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is defined by the equation $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(x^i)^2 = 1$ for $p=(p^1, \dots, p^{n+1}) \in S^n$. Show that a neccessary and sufficient condition for $$X_p=\sum a^i \partial / \partial x^i \mid_p \in T_p(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$$ to be tangent to $S^n$ at $p$ is $\sum_{i} a^i p^i = 0$.

I'm trying to understand what the problem is saying and I sort of get the last sum as saying that the dot product of $a$ and $p$ is zero, but this isn't quite right as $a^i$'s are smooth functions not vectors so the dot product doesn't really make sense.

If we assume that $X_p=\sum a^i \partial / \partial x^i \mid_p$ is tangent to $S^n$ at $p$ how can we argue that $\sum_{i} a^i p^i = 0$ should hold? I couldn't find any conditions for the tangency at the book introduction to manifolds by Tu.

Comment: Each $a^i$ is a smooth function of $p$. Evaluating $(a^1,\ldots,a^{n+1})$ at $p$ gives a vector $(a^1(p),\ldots,a^{n+1}(p))\in \Bbb R^{n+1}$, and it makes sense to ask whether this vector is orthogonal to $p\in \Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.5 In Tu's Introduction to Manifolds gives a key insight. I recall it here. Let $f: \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ be smooth, $S = f^{-1}(0)$ be a regular submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, $p = (p^1, \dots, p^{n+1}) \in S$, and $v \in T_pS$. Make the identification $(v^1, \dots, v^{n+1}) = i_{*,p}v$ where $i : S \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is the inclusion.

Let $c : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S$ be a curve with $c(0) = p$ and $c'(0) = (v^1, \dots, v^{n+1})$. Then, $f(c(t)) = 0$ for all $t$ and therefore $$ 0 = \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0} (f\circ c) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r^i}(c(0)) (c^i)'(0) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r^i}(p) v^i.$$

Let us return to the case of the sphere $S^n$. Here, we should just take $f$ to be the map $f(r_1, \dots, r_{n+1}) = -1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} r_i^2$ so that $f^{-1}(0) = S^n$, and put $(v^1, \dots, v^{n+1}) = (a^1, \dots, a^{n+1})$.

The above argument tells us that $T_pS^n \subset \ker \varphi$, where $\varphi : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ is the linear functional defined by $\varphi(e_i) = p^i$. Now, $\varphi$ is nonzero since $p\in S^n$ implies $p_i\neq 0$ for some $i$, and thus $\dim \ker \varphi = n = \dim T_pS^n$. Hence $T_pS^n = \ker \varphi = \{(a^1, \dots, a^{n+1}) : \sum_i a^ip^i = 0\}$.